# How to make a mongoose query using another model to get last registered position?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have made a model to register a device position every 'x' time. So my problem is when I want to get the actual position, given the models shown, because I'm pretty new to mongoose and I'm not sure how to navigate to the last position id (which is an ISODate) getting the Device first.

I've tried a javascript function where I get the position array and compare the id's (dates) so I get the last one, but I think it will be more efficient to get the last position with the query itself.

The models:

```
const positionSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Date, 
    lat: String, 
    lng: String
});
const DeviceGPSSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    name: String,
    group_id: String,
    position: [positionSchema]
});
```

The route app

```
router.post('/map', async (req, res) => {
        const device = await DeviceGPS.findById(req.id);
    var positions = device.position;

    var {lat, lng} = getLastPosition(positions);

    var geoparams = {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
    };

    res.render('map',{geoparams});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` and `$unwind` for finding the latest `position id`.

```
const data = await DeviceGPS.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: req.id,
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$position",        
    },
    {
        $sort: {'position._id': -1} // sort by position id (date) in desc order
    },
    {
        $limit: 1 // select only the last record
    }
]);
if(data.length > 0) {
    const position = data[0].position;
}
```